# Segmentation fault issue in inserting node in a Binary search tree

Tags: pointers, binary-search-tree, insertion

I am confused with the concept of assignment and allocation of node pointer Like When I have to need only assign a node not allocation. Please explain why am I getting SEGMENTATION fault in below code-

```
Node* insert(Node* node, int data)
{
    int x=data;
    Node* nnode=new Node(data);
    //nnode=Node(data);
    Node* curr;
    curr=node;
    while(1){
        if(curr){
            node=nnode;
            break;
        }
        else{
                if(curr->data <x){
                    if(curr->right==NULL){
                        curr->right=nnode;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                       curr=curr->right; 
                    }

                }
                else if(curr->data >x){
                    if(curr->left==NULL){
                        curr->left=nnode;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                       curr=curr->left; 
                    }
                }
        }

    }
    return node;
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fix the first if statement with the following, your code works fine!

```cpp
// if (curr) {
if (curr == NULL) {
```

Here is the test code and output.

```cpp
int main()
{
    //   10
    //  /  \
    // 8   100
    //     /
    //    50
    Node* root = insert(nullptr, 10);
    root = insert(root, 8);
    root = insert(root, 100);
    root = insert(root, 50);
    std::cout << root->data << std::endl;
    std::cout << root->left->data << std::endl;
    std::cout << root->right->data << std::endl;
    std::cout << root->right->left->data << std::endl;
}
```

```sh
$ ./a.out
10
8
100
50
```